# Dynamic HTML code through .cs code using Literal control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to generate HTML code from the back-end file (.cs) to produce the output in .aspx. I'm unable to figure out why when I don't use a method call and directly use Text="HTML", the literal control works perfectly fine with the correct out. However, if I use a method call Text="<%#: methodCall() %>, the output is just a string and it isn't giving the right output.

Here's what I mean:

**Direct text version:**

`<asp:Literal ID="literal" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Text="<b>bold</b><br/><i>italic</i><br/>"/>`

Output:
**bold**
*italic*

**Method call version:**

```
<asp:Literal ID="literal" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Text="<%#: getDetails() %>"/>
```

Output:

```
<b>bold</b><br/><i>italic</i><br/>
```

Method for this is:

```
public string getDetails()
{
   return "<b>bold</b><br/><i>italic</i><br/>";
}
```

Expected outcome:
**bold**
*italic*

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how I can resolve this?

Edit: 
I intend to do data binding so in the end, it would be...

```
<%#: getDetails(string, string, string, string) %>
```

Comment: It looks like when you use <%# getDetails() %> it is HTML encoding the output. I'm pretty sure you can call a method on the code-behind using <% getDetails() %> which may avoid the encoding.

Comment: @CraigW. While that does explain the result, data-binding does not AFAIK apply any encoding/transformation beyond conversion to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the following code to the code behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind(); 
    }
```

alternatively you might just use the `<% =getDetails() %>` wherever you want the text instead of using literal control

Comment: What if I want to use `getDetails(Item.Name, Item.Number, Item.Price, Item.Color)` where there is item binding involved?

Comment: you should be using the above trick rather than using literals. <% =obj.item %> also works well

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<asp:Literal ID="literal" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Text="<%# Server.HtmlEncode(getDetails()) %>"/>
```

Comment: From the reported output the result is *already* being HTML-encoded. See the "Output" and "Expected outcome" sections.